# Mail forwarding in PHP

Tags: php, email, forward

I am developing a dynamic mail forwarding component for a website.

The concept is that
- a user will send an email with arbitrary content to a special email address on the server
- based on the "to" and "subject" line content, the system will forward the email to a group of (external) email addresses that are pulled from a mysql database

I'm running on a shared webhost (Bluehost), so I don't think I have any advanced access to the mail infrastructure to do this for me (no .forward files, for example).  The target email list is dynamic, so I can't use cPanel to set up static forwarding.

I have the incoming mail coming to a PHP script, but the processing looks challenging, especially for the MIME parts - multipart, attachments, etc.  I have looked at the PEAR Mail / MIME stuff, but it seems overkill to completely decode and re-encode the msg...

Any tips?

Comment: I don't understand; how is the mail coming into PHP if you don't have access to the mail infrastructure?  Is your script polling a mailbox?  Regardless, this really doesn't strike me as a task for which PHP is well-suited.  I would recommend getting a VPS (for as low as $10/mo for a minimal instance) and handling this at the SMTP level.

Comment: You say the target email list is dynamic. How is the list managed?

Comment: While you certainly **can** do this in PHP, why not use one of the thousands of off-the-shelf products for this?  They will be faster (as they are multi-threaded), help you prevent your e-mails from getting stuck in spam folders, and will save you a lot of money and hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I use phpMailer for sending email from PHP.

I implemented exactly the same concept in mod_perl a few years back. Be aware that much of your outgoing email will likely be blocked if you send a significant volume. And if your system can be hacked (and that sounds at least plausible), spammers may find it and use your system, which would then lead to all your outgoing email being blocked.

Sending email is more difficult than it should be (if considering only the tech) thanks to spam and spam filters. These days I often find it easier to write code which uses a third-party service to actually send the emails, feeding the addresses over an API. I've had good luck with MailChimp and Contactology APIs recently.

EDIT: as for the incoming email:  If you weren't in a shared hosting situation, it wouldn't be that hard - simply capture it, strip the headers, and pipe it back out to a new address. I'd have to agree with Conrad I guess on that point -- a shared host PHP script seems like a rather sub-optimal environment to try and solve this problem. If you can't use system() to pipe it back out directly the the mail infrastructure, I think you do have to completely parse the incoming email and reassemble it.

Comment: Sounds like OP is more concerned with how to capture the inbound email and parse it than with the actual sending.